# How to catch exception from .net httphandler at javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, httphandler

i am trying to catch exception from httphandler to javascript frontend.
The problem is that xhr responsetext contain a full html.

I didn't found any effective way to extract the actual error message

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what you actually need.
If you need to get current error message to UI, then you can do it like this:

```
 public class ClientErrorHandler : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
 {
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {   
       if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) 
       {         
           var response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
           response.Write(filterContext.Exception.Message);
           response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
           filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
 }
```

You can add this attribute where you need (may be even base controller or as a global filter) and it checks if incoming request was from javascript and if yes, writes to response only error message.

If you don't need actual message, you can simply check status code of returned request:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    500: function(xhr) {
      if(window.console) console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

on the backend side. set Response.StatusCode to 500
And Write your exception's message using Response.Write